# using bringSubviewToFront within touchesBegan and touchesEnded for image frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having great difficulty trying to create a frame from an imageView, and then bringing it to the front. It works for the last image I use it in the viewDidLoad, but I need to bring it into my touchesBegan method.

When I use it in the touchesEnded method, it works, but only the second time I press the button, seeing as this is only executed when the button is released. So I don't see why it shouldn't just work in the touchesBegan method. Instead of working, it simply makes the image just disappear!

Heres the code I have:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == _imageOne){
        CGRect newFrame = _imageOne.frame;
        newFrame.size.width += 280;
        newFrame.size.height += 280;
        newFrame.origin.x -= 3.2;
        newFrame.origin.y += 100;
        _imageOne.frame = newFrame;
        [_imageOne.superview bringSubviewToFront:_imageOne];
    }
    else if ([touch view] == _imageTwo)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = _imageTwo.frame;
        newFrame.size.width += 280;
        newFrame.size.height += 280;
        newFrame.origin.x -= 95;
        newFrame.origin.y += 100;
        _imageTwo.frame = newFrame;
    }
    else if ([touch view] == _imageThree)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = _imageThree.frame;
        newFrame.size.width += 280;
        newFrame.size.height += 280;
        newFrame.origin.x -= 185;
        newFrame.origin.y += 100;
        _imageThree.frame = newFrame;
    }
}
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == _imageOne)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = _imageOne.frame;
        newFrame.size.width -= 280;
        newFrame.size.height -= 280;
        newFrame.origin.x += 3.2;
        newFrame.origin.y -= 100;
        _imageOne.frame = newFrame;
    }
    else if ([touch view] == _imageTwo)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = _imageTwo.frame;
        newFrame.size.width -= 280;
        newFrame.size.height -= 280;
        newFrame.origin.x += 95;
        newFrame.origin.y -= 100;
        _imageTwo.frame = newFrame;
    }
    else if ([touch view] == _imageThree)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = _imageThree.frame;
        newFrame.size.width -= 280;
        newFrame.size.height -= 280;
        newFrame.origin.x += 185;
        newFrame.origin.y -= 100;
        _imageThree.frame = newFrame;
    }
}
```

Any help is HUGELY appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do touch code slightly differently, you could give this a try.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in [event allTouches]) {

        for (UIImageView *image in _images) {
            point = [touch locationInView:image];
            inside = [image pointInside:point withEvent:event];

            if (inside) {
                // your activation code
            }
        }
    }
}
```